# Bound Controls vs ADO.NET Manual coding

Tags: asp.net

Which is better; using the wizard bind controls or working with ADO.NET objects manually from the performance point of view.

Comment: I know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882817/object-datasource-or-code-behind-which-is-better doesn't really answer your question, but it does discuss some pros and cons and you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you would be able to squeeze more performance going manual because you would have tighter control over what happens and when.  However, depending on your app, the small gains you might get may not be worth the extra development time compared with using drag/drop/wizards.
It also depends on the size and complexity of your pages, sometimes the wizards just can't handle what you want to do since they were designed for simple scenarios.